# Dunder methods like __rsub__ not working in pytest

Tags: python

Lets say I have a class `Foo`. I want to be able to do something like

```
a = Foo()
print(10 - a)
```

I've defined the `__sub__` and `__rsub__` methods in `Foo` and they work when I test it in the console.

However, when I use it in Pytest it keeps giving me `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'Foo'`.

It's also ignoring `__rdiv__`, but not `__radd__` or `__rmul__`. Is there something special about Pytest?

Comment: Can you show how are you defining `__rsub__`?

Comment: Looks like `__rsub__` isn't the issue. This only happens within pytest.

Answer (score 0):

this simple snippet is working :

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.x - other
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return other - self.x
```

```py
from foo import Foo

def test_a():
    assert Foo(5) - 10 == -5

def test_b():
    assert 10 - Foo(5) == 5
```

```
======================================================================================= test session starts =======================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.5, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: xxx
collected 2 items

test_foo.py ..                                                                                                                                                                              [100%]

======================================================================================== 2 passed in 0.01s ========================================================================================
```

maybe you can  snippet of your code

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. Found the issue.

Pytest imported my library using the version already installed instead of from source. The version installed doesn't have `__rsub__` properly implemented.